# Microsoft PPL parallel_for_each with boost filesystem directory_iterator

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, boost, c++11

using Visual Studio 2010 SP1

so i have a std::for_each iterating on lots of files using the boost::filesystem library.
since those iterations dont mess with each other i was trying to get multi threading working on it, so im trying to use VS 2010 library PPL.

old: `for_each(directory_iterator(path), directory_iterator(), <lambda function>);`
new: `parallel_for_each(directory_iterator(path), directory_iterator(), <lambda function>);`

thing is, the parallel_for_each one doesnt compile because it asks for a random access iterator or a forward access iterator which i assume directory_iterator is not.
is there a way i can make directory_iterator work in this case? maybe with a diferent iterator that i dont know about or maybe some kind of cast?

tried searching for an answer on the web, but PPL with boost isnt really that much talked yet.

thanks in advance.

Comment: A workaround could be iterating through all directories and adding them to a container that support random access iterators. Then you can use parallel_for_each on the new container.

Comment: "*it asks for a random access iterator or a forward access iterator which i assume directory_iterator is not*" Correct -- `directory_iterator` is a [single pass iterator](http://www.boost.org/libs/iterator/doc/new-iter-concepts.html#single-pass-iterators-lib-single-pass-iterators).

Comment: thanks for the tips. Fox32: now i feel dumb for not having thought about that.. tried it with some non-clean code and it worked, not only that but i won a LOT of performance by just adding a few lines of code. thanks again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If most of your time is spent loading files, you're only slowing yourself down by trying to load multiple files. That said, if your work is processing-bound, you could do something like this:

```
for each file // serial
{
    load file into memory
    spawn task to process file // concurrent
}

wait until tasks to complete
```

For that, you'll want to use the [tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492427.aspx).

Comment: thanks for the input. actually i was loading files in parallel which is ofc an horrible ideia but the code is still very dirty. funny thing is even when loading files in parallel (not just processing them in parallel) the performance of the program was way better than the serial version. now im going to try tasks following your example and see how it goes, ill report my findings after in case someone in the future wants to know. thanks again.

Comment: @sap: I myself want to know the results. :)